# Intersection of k structured trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, permutation, graph-algorithm

A tree `T` will be called *structured* if for every `d`, all nodes at distance `d` from the root contain the same type of data.

Our goal is to construct a new tree `T'` which is the "intersection" of some subtrees of `T`.

That is, `T'` has the same *structure* (same data types at the same order) as `T`, and every node `v` in `T'` is the result of an agreement/intersection of corresponding nodes in `T`.

**An example will show this best:**

In the tree `T` below, each leaf represents a colored permutation of 2 elements.

Our goal is to find all possible colored permutations of 3 elements: that are both allowed permutations by the restrictions in `T`, and have the same color. For example, `231` is an allowed permutation but doesn't have a mutual color.

[image: example of constructing T' from T]

**Well then, how should I construct `T'`? what data structure should I use?**

My intuition says a BFS-style algorithm will get the job done nicely, yet I suspect a better logic could be applied.

For example, here is one idea I had and I am not sure how to proceed with: maybe I can store `T` in some fancy database, compute all allowed permutations together, and then call the corresponding colored leaves?

Comment: The rules of the problem are not clear to me. Can you give a more formalized specification? I understand that the subtrees marked in blue and red in `T'` are obtained by merging the subtrees marked in blue and red in `T`. It seems the rule for merging sets is taking the union, the rule for merging sequences is creating a new sequence that respects each ordering (so `[1,2]` and `[2,3]` can be merged to `[1,2,3]`, but `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` are not mergeable). Nodes with a colors can only be merged if they have the same color.

Comment: What exactly would be the input of the algorithm? Would it be `T` and a list of lists of subtrees that you want to have merged in `T'` (so in your example a list containing the list of blue subtrees and the list of red subtrees), so the problem is checking if these lists are mergeable? Or would the input only be `T` and the problem is to identify all mergeable subtrees? If the latter, it's not clear to me why in your example `{1,2} -> [1,2] -> blue` cannot be merged with `{1,3} -> [3,1] -> blue` into `{1,2,3} -> [3,1,2] -> blue`.

Comment: The latter is the case, and your example is not allowed because [3,2] is a sub-permutation of [3,1,2], but [3,2] is not allowed.

Comment: BTW, I ended up solving this using a DNA-alignment inspired algorithm, you can see the details [here](https://github.com/DalyaG/PublicSpeaking/tree/master/SequnceAlignmentForRideSharing).